# Select Command Parameters C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I need to get the value of SelectCommand.Parameters

Can you Help me ?

```
string sql = "SELECT area, login, senha FROM tbl_usuarios WHERE login = '" + login + "' AND senha = '" + senha + "'";
adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
dataTable = new DataTable();

adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("login", DbType.String);
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("senha", DbType.String);

string a = adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(@"area", DbType.Int16); // Error Coversion
Session.Add("ar", a);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you are trying to assign the return type from the Add Method (which is a SqlParameter) to a string.

See [SqlParameterCollection.Add Method (String, SqlDbType)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wbys3e9s.aspx)

I thing what you are looking for is something like

```
SqlParameter a = adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(@"area", DbType.Int16);
```

Answer (score 0):

check your code on MSDN : [SqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.selectcommand%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

maybe you need is:

get the value on your datatable:

```
string sql = "SELECT area, login, senha FROM tbl_usuarios WHERE login = '" + login + "' AND senha = '" + senha + "'";
adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
dataTable = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(dataTable);

string a  = dataTable.Rows["area"].toString(); //get area value..
Session.Add("ar", a);
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, however the Add method returns a type of SqlParameter, so this:

```
string a = adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(@"area", DbType.Int16);
```

Is wrong.. it needs to be:

```
SqlParameter a = adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(@"area", DbType.Int16);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        bool encontrou = false;
        string sql = "SELECT area, login, senha FROM tbl_usuarios WHERE login = '" + login + "' AND senha = '" + senha + "'";
        command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while(dataReader.Read())
            {
                string area = dataReader["area"].ToString();
                Session.Add("area", area);
                encontrou = true;
            }
        }
```